# Android Studio List from API

Tags: android, list, api

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and I've gone through most of the BigNerdRanch's guide on it. I've done some research but I can't seem to find a method of taking the information from an [API](http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city=Dubai&country=AE&method=2) and then proceeding to list the information. Also, how would could I sort through the info from the API to find object such as time? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is official information with sample app exactly about this. 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

good luck!